# Firefox Add-on: How can I paste clipboard to a textarea?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

```
var clipboard = require("sdk/clipboard");
clipboard.set("Something Here!");
var contents = clipboard.get();
```

How can I make it automatically paste the text inside clipboard to a textarea in a real page, by some handler?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to do, please add more context. The best way to inject text into a textarea would instead be to use a content script: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`page-mod`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) and sent the clipboard data via a message to that `page-mod`, and have the `page-mod` content script change the `.value` of the `<textarea>` upon receiving the message.